# Will any Gasket Work on a Ford L4 Engine?

Tags: gasket

I want to know would any Ford L4 Gasket work on any Ford L4 Engine? Are The parts interchangeable or do different L4 Ford Engines have different variation and if so how many ? Also just as a side question is the same true for all gaskets? Will they work on the manufacturer engine type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the par numbers cross reference, then they should be interchangeable. Otherwise they may not.

In some cases the difference in a gasket my not be the shape, but the materials as well. So even a gasket that appears to fit may not function correctly.

From a production standpoint, all the L4 motors of the same model year would have a fair likelihood of having interchangeable parts - **but not necessarily**. It really depends on what the engineers decided to change on the motor, and sometime they may have decided to change the gasket design as well. The only way to know for sure is to check the part numbers.